# Without Count, Query patients who have more than two preconditions, Patientinformation and Preconditions are my tables, PatientID is the shared key

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

```
select Fname, Lname
from Patientinformation
where PatientID in (Select distinctrow PatientID 
                        from Preconditions
                        where (Patientinformation.PatientID = Preconditions.PatientID)>=2
                       );
```

This shows no error, but I'm getting zero results

Comment: Thank You Akina, how can I check if the PatientID matches more than one PreCondition, without using the count Function?

Comment: Why you want NOT to use COUNT()?

Comment: Part of my assignment.

Comment: WIll do, Thank you :)

Comment: `distinctrow` is not normally used in MySQL.  It is curious that your query has that construct.

Comment: I am trying out evreything since I am not supposed to use count function, and I dont have much experience coding with SQL

Answer (score 0):

> This shows no error, but I'm getting zero results

`(Patientinformation.PatientID = Preconditions.PatientID)` may be NULL, TRUE or FALSE which is treated as NULL, 1 or 0 respectively.

So `(Patientinformation.PatientID = Preconditions.PatientID)>=2` is `NULL >= 2`, `0 >= 2` or `1 >= 2` - i.e. it is never TRUE.

---

> how can I check if the PatientID matches more than one PreCondition, without using the count Function? – sandeep venkat
>
> Why you want NOT to use COUNT()? – Akina
>
> Part of my assignment. – sandeep venkat

Use, for example

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.columns
FROM t1
JOIN t2 t21 ON t1.somecolumn = t21.somecolumn
JOIN t2 t22 ON t1.somecolumn = t22.somecolumn AND t21.id != t22.id
```

or

```
SELECT t1.columns
FROM t1
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM t2 t21
               WHERE t1.somecolumn = t21.somecolumn
                 AND EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                              FROM t2 t22
                              WHERE t21.somecolumn = t22.somecolumn
                                AND t21.id != t22.id ) )
```

Comment: I tried both, both of them are returning zero records.

Comment: @sandeepvenkat Create sample online fiddle, add link to the question, and show desired output for this fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the patient ids using:

```
select PatientID 
from Preconditions p
group by PatientID
having count(*) > 2;
```

Then you can combine this with the patient information.  `IN` is fine (although it would not be my first choice):

```
select pi.Fname, pi.Lname
from Patientinformation pi
where pi.PatientID in (select p.PatientID 
                       from Preconditions p
                       group by PatientID
                       having count(*) > 2
                      );
```